# How to add certificate to Windows Credential Manager?

Tags: windows, certificate, credentials

How do you add a certificate from the personal store as a certificate based credential in Windows `Credential Manager`?

When I click on Open the Certificate Manager it just takes me to the Certificate Manager and there is no way to actually select the certificate to be added as a certificate based credential.

It doesn't make any difference what I type in "Internet or network address".  When I press "Select certificate" it just asks me to insert a smart card.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is working as designed.  As stated in the help text, `To use a certificate in a certificate-based credential, it needs to be saved in your Personal store in Certificate Manager`.

Opening the certificate manager is just a way of giving you an opportunity to [import the desired certificate](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc776889%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) to that particular store.  I'm going to make an assumption here, that your certmgr window looks like the below screencip when you open up the Personal certificate store, and that's the problem.

[image]

Any certificate you want managed through Credential manager needs to be in that certificate store.

Once you actually have a certificate in your user's personal store, you'll be able to select it with the `Select certificate` button, as in the screen clip below.  (I just have the one certificate for my domain user, and it's a pain to add more, given that my normal user is not an admin on the machine, so I'm not going to jump through that hoop for a screen clip.)

[image]

Comment: When I click on "Select Certificate" it just asks me to insert a smart card. It does not ask to select a certificate. Why is it doing that?

Comment: @CJ7 Because you don't have any certificates in the Personal certificate store?

Comment: But I do have a certificate in the Personal certificate store.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have a certificate with the Client Authentication purpose that is not expired.